# Can I make a label multilines?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel called homeLabel, and I want this label to adjust its size and drop a new line when appropriate...I'm creating a note in one view controller and the label contains one of the notes...

this is how i set up the label in view did load:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    self.homeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Candara-Bold" size:40];
    self.homeLabel.text = stackTableViewController.currentTarget;

}
```

how can i make this outlet multiline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **numberOfLines** to 0 to allow for any number of lines.

```
yourlabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Also an alternative is to use UITextView which is really meant for multilines.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following line to you code

```
self.homeLabel.numberOfLines = 0; //0 to allow any number of line or specify any number that you want to be the max number of lines
self.homeLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```